# is there android mobile phones/devices which have NFC reader in front part of

Tags: android, nfc, device, nfc-p2p

I need first of all to know if there is Android mobile devices supporting NFC and which have its NFC reader on the front part of the mobile/on the screen. Goal: such device is planned to use in restaurant/museum for visitors with NFC cards which attaching their NFC card to the screen/front part of the device will see on the screen text message about if they have access and other info

Or is there any devices supporting Android and NFC having screen and NFC reader on the front part of them.

Thank you so much for any information!

Comment: Why not just have them attach it to the back? Get a tablet and make an improvised holder on the back of it that customers can put their cards into.

Comment: Why not? Because it's stupid. Nobody wants to put the card in. "near field" makes no sense if you have to handle it like magnetic stripe.

Comment: Looks like near field ain't exactly so near, from way too many perspectives...

Answer (score 1):

The Google Nexus 10 tablet has two antenna, one back and one front side located at the camera. That should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Asus Zenfone 4, as per their Q&A
https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1034126/

and manual (instructing users to tap the NFC terminal face down)

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested my own Huawei Nova 3 - it can read NFC card about 1cm above screen.

Answer (score 0):

We use external NFC reader but the Sony Z2 could read NFC on front and on back some people say...